# Video.js Redirect to URL Once Video Has Ended

Tags: javascript, html5-video, flash, video.js

I tried searching all over and couldn't find an answer.

this code doesn't work on latest version video.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_V_("example_video_1").ready(function(){
this.addEvent("ended", function(){
{window.location = "www.google.com"}
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
videojs("example_video_1").on("ended", function() {
  window.location = "http://www.google.com";
});
```